# Performance of OS install on SD vs USB 3

Tags: usb, sd-card, pi-4, usb3

I was wondering if I should think about installing the OS on a USB 3.0 stick and using the USB 3.0 port rather than the Class 10 Micro SD card  to enhance read/write speeds.

Is there a performance increase using the USB 3 interface rather than the SD card?

Comment: depends on the USB 3.0 stick - they're not all made equal!!

Comment: by the way, you can't boot from USB on the pi 4 - not yet anyway

Answer (score 1):

The fastest SD card, equipped with the UHS-II interface, offers a reading speed of 312 MB/s, less than half the USB 3.0 standard (640 MB/s).

After, the reading speed may vary from one key to another...

That's why I've chose a usb3 too :)

Life is increased on usb 3!

Comment: Comparing maximum speeds of interfaces is rather pointless. Good luck finding a USB stick which actually provides that speed.

Comment: Look at :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0

Comment: My server run since 5 years with my USB key ;)